# How does Spotify connect to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, air

I have an iPad app that was built in Adobe Air, the app currently requires that users register and login.

What I would like is for users to login with their Facebook account, but this would require a Facebook dialog to appear within my app, either with `StageWebView` or in a browser window.

The Spotify client on windows PC doesn't show this dialog, instead you can enter your FB credentials into a normal text box:

[image]

This is how I would like my iPad app to behave, so I can keep my current login form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the result of a special partnership between Facebook and Spotify. Generally, Facebook doesn't want you collecting users' passwords on your forms as a security precaution.

Comment: Thanks, seems you're right. I also just found this:http://www.quora.com/Facebook-API/How-does-Spotifys-mobile-signin-allow-you-to-use-your-Facebook-account